getdents() syscall appears to be returning different results within a container
I'm trying to read what type of file /dev/null is. If I use stat() it reports correctly that it's a character device.
If I use getdents(), it also reports that it's a character device - unless I run it in a container, in which case it says it's a regular file!
Why does running it in a container give different results?
This was tested on recent versions of docker and podman giving the same results, using the ubuntu:22.04 image.
Below is reproduction code - the stat() approach always works, but getdents causes the assert to fail when run inside a container. Also worth noting that the code doesn't always get reproduced - on some systems / containers it seems to still work fine.
(Tested on linux 6.8.2-arch2-1 and podman 5.0.0)
#include <assert.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

struct linux_dirent {
    long           d_ino;
    off_t          d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char           d_name[];
};

int main() {
    // stat approach

    struct stat st;
    stat("/dev/null", &st);

    printf("stat type: %d\n", st.st_mode & S_IFMT);

    assert((st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFCHR);

    // getdirents approach

    int fd, nread;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct linux_dirent *d;
    int bpos;
    char d_type;

    fd = open("/dev", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);

    for (;;) {
        nread = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);

        for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;) {
            d = (struct linux_dirent *)(buf + bpos);
            if (strcmp(d->d_name, "null") == 0) {
                d_type = *(buf + bpos + d->d_reclen - 1);
                printf("getdents type: %d\n", d_type);
                assert(d_type == DT_CHR);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            bpos += d->d_reclen;
        }
    }
    close(fd);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


Incidentally, this is a fun problem, because the answer tells us something about the different in how stat() and readdir() operate, and it also tells us something about the container environment is put together. Neat! Thanks for posting.

FWIW, I cannot reproduce in 6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic and Docker version 26.0.0, build 2ae903e

Docker (typically) isn't running rootless; you'll see that if you run Podman as root, you don't get this behavior, either. The way /dev is set up differs between the root-full and root-less configurations.

It turns out that getdirents is telling you the truth!
If we enter a rootless podman container and run mount, we see that /dev/null is actually a bind mount (the -v ... here is just so that I have access to your sample code from inside the container):
$ podman run -it --rm  -v $PWD:/src:z fedora:39
[root@00af7efc8781 /]# mount |grep /dev/null
devtmpfs on /dev/null type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,seclabel,size=4096k,nr_inodes=8186582,mode=755,inode64)

What do we see if we unmount that bind mount? Let's find out:

First, we need the container pid:
$ podman container inspect -l | jq .[0].State.Pid
50502


With that, we can use nsenter to enter the associated mount and pid namespaces:
$ sudo nsenter -t 50502 -m -p


And finally we can unmount the /dev/null bind mount:
[root@fizzgig /]# umount /dev/null



Now, we see:
[root@fizzgig /]# ls -l /dev/null
-rwx------. 1 21937 21937 0 Apr  2 20:03 /dev/null

Surprise, it's a file!

Calling getdirents is reading directory entries from /dev, which means it doesn't know about the bind mounts...so you see the d_type of the underlying entry.

Unrelated to your question...instead of calling getdirent directly, you can use readdir(3) and not have to define your own struct and use syscall (and still get the same behavior).

Thanks for this great answer, though it leaves me with even more doubts. Why doesn't getdents() "know about bind mounts"? How can I ascertain that from its man page? Why is that an acceptable behavior (i.e. inquiring about a file in different ways returns different answers)?

A directory is effectively a "file" that contains a list of entries. The contents of the "directory file" don't change just because you've bind mounted something on top of one of the files contained in the directory. By reading directly from the directory you are effectively "going behind" the VFS layer. This is one of the reasons why tools like ls call stat() on each individual file in a directory, rather than just printing out the results of readdir().
